# How do I read LookUp fields with multiple values in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sharepoint, moss

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I have inherited an old .NET project based on SharePoint 2007 and have designed and external core library which merely accesses SP data, therefore making SP just a backend.  Yes, I know it would be better to migrate to SQL, but the client doesn't agree.

The previous developers used a simple read method to read the data in a SP list:

```
  SPList list = CurrentRootWeb.Lists["SomeListName"];
```

And then they access list properties through a dictionary of sorts (i.e. for each item in list, get item["SomeValue"]).

I am not skilled in SharePoint, so I don't know if this is the most efficient manner to go about accessing it's data.

## Problem

How do I read LookUp fields with multiple values in SharePoint?

Every property they request seems to want a string in return.  So `item[SomeString]` is okay, but `item[SomeList]` makes everything barf!  I would have thought that a multi-value lookup list column comes in as a serialized or delimited string holding the selected values (example: "red;blue;green").  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of the `SPField`s in the list's fields, you need to test the field's `Type`.

If the type is `SPFieldType.MultiChoice`, then you cast the `SPField` to `SPFieldChoice` and access the `Choices` collection, which is a `StringCollection`.

Comment: Thanks competent_tech!  I am very *incompetent* when it comes to SharePoint--can you please tell me how to test the type in code?  Only if you know without referencing anything.  Thanks!

Comment: That's going to depend on how you are accessing the fields. I assume that your code is doing something like foreach (SPField oField in list.Fields); if so, then you can just say: if (oField.Type == SPFieldType.MultiChoice)

Answer (score 9):

If you are specifically interested in LookUp fields with multiple values not just MultiChoice feilds, then following code should help:

```
item.Fields["LookFieldName"].Type == SPFieldType.Lookup;
SPFieldLookup LookUpField = item.Fields["LookFieldName"] as SPFieldLookup;
if (LookUpField.AllowMultipleValues)
{
    SPFieldLookupValueCollection valueCollection = item[Field.Id] as SPFieldLookupValueCollection;

    string[] arrLookupValues = (from SPFieldLookupValue val in valueCollection select val.LookupValue).ToArray<string>();


 }
```

Comment: As a newbie sharepoint developer, this answer was very helpful and hard to find.  Thanks also for giving a great example with SPLinq.